# Using Series Reversion for finding inverse of $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+3x+2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inverse-function

The question only asks to find the values of $a$ for which the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+3x+2$ exists. To solve for the set of values of $a$, we can just set $f'(x)\ge0$ such that the equality only holds at discrete points. Then solving inequality, using the discriminant gives that $|a|\lt3$.

I read about [Series Reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), and tried to apply it for this polynomial but it is not clear as to how to coefficents of the inverse power series solution calculated [**here**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html). It would be great if someone could illustrate it with this example at hand, and explain the computation of the coefficients of the inverse power series solution in the link (boldfaced). Thanks

---

**Update $1$**:

Let's simplify the problem, say find the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$. So how to go about, can we comment on the degree of $f^{-1}(x)$ if its a polynomial function which it is unlikely to be. Besides, since we know its roots as it factorizes as $(x+1)(x^2+2)$, how can that be helpful in determining the inverse.

Comment: You can find treatments of "reversion of series" (this is the more useful phrase to google) in [some 1800s algebra texts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reversion+of+series%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks). Also, if you have access to JSTOR (I don't), then [this search](https://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?q0=%22reversion+of+series%22) will likely be very useful. Some of the older items (before 1910, maybe even before 1920) may be freely available, however.

Comment: But if you are really being asked precisely when the inverse exists, then you have answered the question, correctly. To me, this question doesn’t seem to involve series at all.

Comment: @Lubin I wanted to know the general procedure to finding inverse of polynomial functions, apart from finding the condition when the inverse exists which is a trivial exercise.

Comment: Well, if you know a root, as in the case $f(x)=x^3+2x$, then it’s easily-enough done by hand. To get a Maclaurin series, just set your trial inverse to be $g(x)=\frac12x+\lambda x^2$, and see what $\lambda$ has to be (answer: $\lambda=0$). Then set your trial inverse to be $\frac12x+\lambda x^3$ and decide on $\lambda$ again. Pain in the neck, of course, and laborious. If you have access to a symbolic algebra program, you can use Newton-Raphson very profitably.

Comment: @Lubin I'm not sure how you got the coefficient of $x$ in the inverse function $g(x)$. Besides what if there is a constant term as well. Can you illustrate with the example I've stated in the updated question with $a=0$? Thanks

Comment: Well if the value of the derivative at $(x,y)$ is $c$, then the derivative of the inverse function at $(y,x)$ is $1/c$. That’s all. Of course you could let the first coefficient be unknown, and solve for it, discovering that it was $1/c$, in this case $\frac12$. At any rate, no mysteries, either way.

Comment: @Lubin And how would we deal with points where the slope is $0$, and also please clarify on how to deal with an additional constant term.

Comment: If the slope is zero, the inverse function can not be described by a power series, at least not in the most obvious variable. If there’s a nonzero constant term, things get much more complicated. The only way I can think of going it would involve very messy approximative computations, far worse than when there’s no constant.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you sir for clarifying on this concept. And thanks for being a part of this discussion. Regards.